# node.js. Есть несколько экземпляров socket.io, как между ними общаться

Tags: node.js

Коллеги, открыл три порта, 80, 2500, 2501. На 80м отправляются страницы, скрипты, стили, картинки грузятся. на 2500 чат. на 2501 загрузка файлов. Хочу по окончанию загрузки файла в 2501 порту послать сообщение на 2500 порт. Как в node.js "обратиться" из одного в другое io, чтоб по 2500 послать сообщение в чат. Заранее благодарю.

```
/* 80 порт */
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('listening 1 on *:80');
});



/* 2500 порт */
var app2 = require('express')();
var http2 = require('http').Server(app2);
var io2 = require('socket.io')(http2);

io2.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.broadcast.emit('msg', "My alert...");
}

http2.listen(80, function(){
  console.log('listening 2 on *:2500');
});



/* 2501 порт */
var app3 = require('express')();
var http3 = require('http').Server(app3);
var io3 = require('socket.io')(http3);

//тут опред. событие как от сюда попасть в io2 и от туда отправить socket.broadcast.emit...

http3.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('listening 3 on *:2501');
});
```

Comment: в `on('connection')` сохраните `socket`, а потом в него отправляйте.

Comment: Suvitruf, получилось, благодарю!

Comment: Как ответ оформил, чтоб можно было зааксептить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в `on('connection')` сохранить `socket`, а потом в него отправлять сообщения.